# kernel tried to execute NX-protected page - exploit attempt? (uid: 0)

Tags: c, linux-kernel

When I try to get some info about cgroup in kernel, I use struct cftypes(after a long time of searching...), but the terminal reminds me as below:

[image]

Comment: Share the complete Kernel OOPS log instead of screenshot of it. You can also have a look at here http://www.kerneloops.org/ for your error.

Comment: thx, this site is fantastic

Comment: Were you doing this in a VM? It mentions QEMU BIOS, which is interesting. If you have a repro (or even better, a snapshot of the VM), it'll be really easy for someone working on cgroups to fix this. That said, it looks like you are using a super old kernel (3.10), and this particular bug may already have been fixed.